# Which to use in Django: ListView or list_detail?

Tags: django, django-urls

I was reading some tutorials and books about [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/).

In [part 4 of the official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/), they wrote an example like this

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from polls.models import Poll

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',
        ListView.as_view(
            queryset=Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5],
            context_object_name='latest_poll_list',
            template_name='polls/index.html')),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        DetailView.as_view(
            model=Poll,
            template_name='polls/detail.html')),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$',
        DetailView.as_view(
            model=Poll,
            template_name='polls/results.html'),
        name='poll_results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'polls.views.vote'),
)
```

I have also been reading [The Definitive Guide to Django: Web Development Done Right, Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143021936X) and when they talked about generic views, they wrote their example like this

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic import list_detail
from mysite.books.models import Publisher

publisher_info = {
    'queryset': Publisher.objects.all(),
    'template_name': 'publisher_list_page.html',
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^publishers/$', list_detail.object_list, publisher_info)
)
```

Should I be using `ListView` or `list_detail`? They both come from `django.views.generic`. If they can both be used, then what's the difference (advantage and disadvantage comparison)?

In case it helps, I'll explain my objective: In my project, I want to list work orders, and then I want a detailed view of each work order that will also contain a list of comments for that order (similar to comments per blog post).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ListView` (class-based) is intended to replace `object_list` (function-based) because there is limited flexibility to extending a function's behavior.

As the [Django (1.4) documentation notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/), the function-based generic views are deprecated in favor of the class-based versions. So use `ListView`, since Django removed `object_list`.

Either way, I prefer to put all the customizations in views.py to avoid cluttering up urls.py, which tends to be a dumping ground of things.

Comment: I don't really understand the Class based generic view documentation. For example, for [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#list-views), why is the entry so short? Where can I find the list of all the methods and variables?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's part of bad documentation on Django's part (partially because of the multiple inheritance). But you can view what they subclass: e.g. - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin

Answer (score 12):

I'm finding Classy useful as an easy way to view an outline of each CBV: http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.list/ListView/

It feels like a missing part of the Django docs now.

Comment: This isn't the accepted answer, but this resource is amazing.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link appears broken :(

Comment: Just checked it and the URL still works for me -- I use it most days. Edited the comment to include Dj 1.6.